# How do you ping between VLANs?

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, layer3, ping

I have created VLANs on the layer 3 switch and I would like to ping between them, how do i do so?

I would like to allow VLAN 2 to ping VLAN 3, how? What command should I use?

```
new#sh ip interf brief vlan 2
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan2                  10.1.4.1        YES manual up                    up


new#sh ip interf brief vlan 3
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan3                  10.1.2.1        YES manual up                    up
```

Comment: Did you enable routing?

Comment: i did yeah, but to ping vlan 3 do i do "ping 10.1.2.1 source 10.1.4.1" ?

Comment: When using a L3 switch, you need the command "ip routing".  When using L2 switches, you need another router (or L3 switch) with a Router on a Stick (RoaS) configuration.

Comment: @Stan234 When you ping, you can use the source option for ping or even if you don't, it will use that IP anyway (considering you don't have your management vlan up up and running with an IP)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your switch has L3 ability, you can issue the ip routing on the global config and then use the ping. Also the L3 communication between VLAN interfaces (as known as SVI on Cisco literature) starts to work. This test can be done either on the switch itself or by the hosts which are connected to their respective VLANs.

Use a extended ping command by using the source address from an SVI interface you've created towards the IP address of the another SVI on this switch.

Once these interfaces are up, and you have setup the IP addresses on the hosts belonging to them, you are able to see the ARP table for each L3 interface (SVI).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. -enable
2. -conf t
3. Enable ip routing if it is available:
4. IP routing (if layer 3 capability is present)
5. end

based on your config....Running an extended ping with the destination address of the vlan you are trying to ping  10.1.2.1 or 10.1.4.1 should be successful after that.